# how to have a div element with multiple lines and text-overflow ellipsis(...) at the end of the last line of the div

Tags: css

i am trying to have a div element, which when i insert a text inside it, the div element's CSS style can break a long text into multiple lines and also when it reaches the div height, the end of the last line gets ellipsis(...)

my div has a static height and width in pixels. 
my problem is that i have tried using "overflow-wrap:break-word", and the ellipsis wont work, but without it, the ellipsis works but the div will only have one line, which i want multiple lines,not one.

```html
<div style="overflow:hidden;white-space:no-wrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow-wrap: break-word;height:50px;width:400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your height is static , Its easy to use the below style.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;width:400px;display: -webkit-box;-webkit-line-clamp: 3;-webkit-box-orient: vertical;"></div>
```

> "-webkit-line-clamp" will specify the ellipsis will appear after the specified number of lines.
>   This will work with the combination of webkit-box-orient: vertical; and display: -webkit-box;

Comment: thanks Girimurugan,does -webkit work on all browsers or only on firefox? and is this the only way? and if the height isn't static, it will be impossible right?

Comment: Even the height is non static also , this css will work, line-clamp style is to specify the number lines to be displayed .